# Cannot access to object prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, javascript-objects

I'm trying to access to an object `prototype` in a node js code. The object is meant to be sent through an API and let the users to use the methods of the object.
The problem is that the returned object does only contain the attributes of the object, not the methods and not the `__proto__`.

Any ideas why ?

```
class foo {
    constructor() {
        this.bar = "bar"
    }

    usefullMethod () {
       return 123
    }
}

var user = new foo()

console.log(user) // {bar: "bar"} does not display usefullMethod function
```

and on express:

```
res.json(user) // returns only object attributes but not the __proto__
```

Comment: The `prototype` property isn’t writable. You should use `foo.prototype.usefulMethod = () => 123;`.

Comment: Concept of stringifying prototype doesn't make much sense. JSON is string data. If you need that client side add it there after json string is parsed to object

Comment: You should be glad JSON doesn't stringily the prototype chain — imagine stringifying an array and get *all* those properties: `lastIndexOf`, `sort`, `map`, `reduce`...or a string `trimStart`, `toUpperCase`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You attempted to overwrite the entire `prototype`, even though you can't. Should be:

```
foo.prototype.usefullMethod = () => 123;
```

Comment: You have to `console.log(user.usefullMethod())`. Of course, you have to ask yourself, why use `.prototype` if you just created the class. Why not just put the method in the class, in this case?

Comment: @AxelMadode Do you expect `console.log(user);` to display `usefullMethod`? Why?

Comment: @Sebastian Simon Before creating this class, I wrote a module with functions 
and then I exported the object. But I got the same problem. My goal is to send this object with all its functions in response to a request from the server. The instance of the received object should allow me to perform client-side operations.